# Regular expression for arithmetic expression

Tags: java, regex, arithmetic-expressions

I,m trying to write a regex to check if the given string is like
a + b,   2 + a + b,    3 + 6 * 9 + 6 * 5 + a * b,     etc...

Only + and * operators.

I tried

`if (str.matches("(\\d|\\w \\+|\\*){1,} \\d|\\w"))`

Unfortunately it only handles cases like  3 * 7  ... (numeric * numeric).

Waiting for your answers, thanks for reading me.

Comment: The character class (ala @AvinashRaj) is clearly better. Purely for educational purposes the problem with your use of the vertical bar is that you didn't group the things before and after. If you wanted `\\+|\\*` then you needed to group them like `(?:\\+|\\*)`. Same with the `\\d|\\w` although that's not so important since \\w includes \\d.

Comment: Matching operators (vs numerical constants / symbolic names) is only the first step of resolving an expression, called tokenizing. The next step is building a parse tree, so that you can properly evaluate parenthesis inside-out, multiplication before addition, etc.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374663/regexp-to-match-basic-arithmetic-with-letters-and-put-them-in-groups/62379691

Blog on tokenizer & parse tree: https://blog.bitsrc.io/parsing-expressions-in-javascript-4c156f0cbaec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `*` and `+` inside a character class.

```
str.matches("\\w(?:\\s[+*]\\s\\w)+");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dI4uH0/2)

Comment: @MedAl since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

This will handle cases of simple and chained calculations

```
[0-9A-Za-a]*( ){0,}([+-/*]( ){0,}[0-9A-Za-a]*( ){0,})*
```

This would match, for example

- 1+2
- 1 + 2
- 1 + a * 14 / 9

(You can change the operators you want by updating `[+-/*]`)

Comment: Why all the `{0,}` instead of just `*`?

Comment: Since you have `*` instead of `+` after the `[0-9a-z]` your re will also match `+` or `+ - * /` or etc

Comment: It's `( ){0,}` so it allows for optional spaces - and only spaces - between the operands

Comment: Yes, but space-star ( ` *` ) does the same thing as open-paren-space-close-paren-open-curly-zero-comma-close-curly. `\s*` would be even better.