# Numerical expression of regex

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language, bnf, ebnf

I need to write a regular expression given by the following bnf form:

```
<expr_num>:=<var>|<sign>|"("<expr_num>")"|<expr_num><operator_num><expr_num>
```

My attempt:

```
var=\w*
sign=+|-
operator_num=[+|-|*|/]
```

However, when I put in the phrase `<expr_num><operator_num><expr_num>` the regular expression is in infinite recursion due `<expr_num>` at the beginning.

My attempt: `(?<expr_num>(?<var>(\[(\w+\d*)\]))|(?<sign>([\+|\-]\g<sign>)|(\d*))|(\((\g<expr_num>)\))|(\g<expr_num>[+|*|-|\/]{1}\g<expr_num>))$`

Error: `recursive call could loop indefinitely`

How to solve this problem?
How to create parser in C# for this expression?

Comment: why isn't `<expr_num>` defined? Could you provide some code?

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*  You need a parser!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in Regex as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845218/regular-expression-for-arithmetic-expression). If you need to do more than just match arithmetic expressions such as evaluating them you get into trouble with Regex. If that is the case you should take [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/02/parsing-expressions-by-precedence-climbing/). That article explains how to parse expression and getting the precedence right.